# Mocha File Execution Order And Async code

Tags: unit-testing, mocha.js, e2e-testing

I have been lazily putting all of my test in one long file. I want to break this down into multiple files but am wondering what is the best (proper) way to assure execution order of these files.

For Example

Prepare (`const testEmail = #Hash#@#hash2#.com`)

1. async can create an account
2. async Can login to account

...

Cleanup Delete testEmail.

All is working fine, but I want 1 and 2 to be in separate files at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you consider only 1 and 2 in separate test, perhaps you can try to use root level hook of mocha

```
// global-test.js
before(function() {
  // create an account
  // do some expectations
});

// login-test.js
describe('login test', function() {
  it('can login to account', function() {
    // test login
  }
]
```

For reference:

https://mochajs.org/#root-level-hooks

Other alternative approach is to use number as your test filename, so mocha will run it start from 1.

```
1-create-account-test.js
2-login-test.js
3-send-email-test.js
```